# Run scheduled task inside Pod in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, influxdb

I have a small instance of influxdb running in my kubernetes cluster.
The data of that instance is stored in a persistent storage.
But I also want to run the backup command from influx at scheduled interval.

```
influxd backup -portable /backuppath
```

What I do now is exec into the pod and run it manually.
Is there a way that I can do this automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution I have used for this question

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: cm-backupscript
  namespace: influx
data:
  backupscript.sh: | 
    #!/bin/bash
    echo 'getting pod name'
    podName=$(kubectl get pods -n influx  --field-selector=status.phase==Running --output=jsonpath={.items..metadata.name})
    echo $podName
    #echo 'create backup'
    kubectl exec -it $podName -n influx -- /mnt/influxBackupScript/influxbackup.sh
    echo 'done'
---
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: backup-cron
  namespace: influx
spec:
  schedule: "0 2 * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          affinity:
            nodeAffinity:
              requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
                nodeSelectorTerms:
                - matchExpressions:
                  - key: kubernetes.io/arch
                    operator: In
                    values:
                    - amd64
          volumes:
          - name: backup-script
            configMap:
              name: cm-backupscript
              defaultMode: 0777
          containers:
          - name: kubectl
            image: bitnami/kubectl:latest
            command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - /mnt/scripts/backupscript.sh
            volumeMounts:
            - name: backup-script
              mountPath: "/mnt/scripts"
          restartPolicy: Never
```

Answer (score 2):

You can consider running a CronJob with [bitnami kubectl](https://bitnami.com/stack/kubectl/containers) which will execute the backup command. This is the same as `exec into the pod and run` except now you automate it with CronJob.

Answer (score 1):

[CronJob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/) is the way to go here. It acts more or less like a crontab, but for Kubernetes.

As an example you could use this

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: backup
spec:
  schedule: 0 8 * * *
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: influxdb-backup
            image: influxdb
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            command: ["/bin/sh"]
            args:
            - "-c"
            - "influxd backup -portable /backuppath"
          restartPolicy: Never
```

This will create a Job, everyday at 08:00, executing `influxd backup -portable /backuppath`. Of course, you have to edit it accordingly, to work on your environment.

Comment: Isn't this going to spin up a new pod with a new instance of influxdb, instead of connecting to the existing one?

Comment: In this case - yes. That's why I specified you need to edit it to fit your environment. I'm not influxdb expert, but I believe adding `-host` argument to `influxd` command, pointing to a proper service, would allow for remote backup.

Answer (score 0):

You can either run it as a cronjob and setup the image to be able to connect to the DB, or you can sidecar it alongside your db pod, and set it to run the `cron` image (i.e. will run as a mostly-idle container in the same pod as your DB)